# how to prevent a DELETE HTTP request from succeeding in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails beginner here..

I have a users resource where I implemented a callback that's supposed to prevent an admin user from deleting herself.

```
before_filter :admin_no_delete,    only: :destroy

def admin_no_delete 
  admin_id = current_user.id if current_user.admin?
  redirect_to root_path if params[:id] == admin_id 
end
```

If this looks familiar to some,  it's from Michael Hartl's rails tutorial, [exercise #10 here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users?version=3.2#sec%3aupdating_deleting_exercises) but I tried to do it differently, not as he suggested.

My (lame) test for this fails

```
    describe "deleting herself should not be permitted" do
      before do
        delete user_path(admin) 
      end
      it { should_not redirect_to(users_path) }
    end
```

But exposing a delete link for the admin user just to test and clicking on that link, it seems like the callback actually succeeds in executing (redirecting to root_path).

I was able to invoke the destroy action using jQuery to delete the record being protected by the callback (using Web Inspector's javascript console):

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/104', type: 'DELETE', success: function(result){alert(result)} })
```

Looking for ideas on how to prevent a DELETE HTTP request from succeeding in this situation.. also any ideas on how to properly test for this kind of situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the test testing anything? Don't you redirect after a successful delete?

Comment: Is the `User` with `id` 104 actually deleted from the database?

Comment: @FrederickCheung - thanks, I realized my mistake there... delete redirects to users_path so that should've been a should_not.. which in that case, the test actually fails

Comment: @Aldo'xoen'Giambelluca - yes, user id 104 gets deleted from the db

Comment: Edited question based of @FrederickCheung's comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: `params[:id]` is a string, while `admin_id` is a Fixnum. You can just change it as follows and it should work:

```rb
redirect_to root_path if params[:id].to_i == admin_id
```

The logic you're using seems a little odd to me, though. Why use a before filter if it's just for one action, and why change the redirect? I think the logic should be directly in the destroy action and look something like this:

```rb
def destroy
  unless current_user.admin? && current_user.id == params[:id].to_i
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
  end
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The tutorial was actually suggesting to put it in the destroy action itself. I was too noob to figure that out - obviously this mistake shows that. I don't think the test I wrote was a good one. Would appreciate any tips to improve it.

Comment: For destroy operations, I think the best way is to check db changes (or the absence thereof, in your case). I sometimes do something like this: `lambda{ delete user_path(admin) }.should change{User.count}.by(0)`

Comment: I thought of checking for count but didn't know how to implement it in that context. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing `admin_id`, an integer with `params[:id]`. Values in `params` are always strings (or arrays/hashes containing more strings) so the comparison will always fail.